# List port for Docker container using command line

Tags: shell, docker

I created an app with react.js and node.js but now I need to use Docker, here is my code:

https://github.com/mruanova/members

I created my Dockerfile and followed the instructions from nodejs.org:

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

The problem is that when i do:

```
docker ps
```

I get nothing:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  COMMAND  CREATED  STATUS  PORTS  NAMES
```

As suggested by the answers here I tried:

```
docker ps -a
```

and I get the ID now but not the PORT:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE  COMMAND  CREATED  STATUS  PORTS  NAMES
123 mruanova/app "node server.js" 7 min ago Exited ? hopeful_williams
987 b7c11ccf6409 "node server.js" 9 min ago Exited ? ecstatic_jennings
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
docker ps -a
```

The process may be running under a user account other than your own.  The `-a` option lists processes from ALL users.

To show the port, first get the CONTAINER id, then:

```
docker port CONTAINER
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I updated my question to include a link to my project in github.

Comment: Awesome.  Glad to hear it!

Comment: I got the ID but not the PORT, I updated the question.

Comment: I am able to test now: curl -i localhost:8080/ap/members